# Find variable by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a jQuery audio player and music list, so, I defined every audio element in variable like:

```
var fade = new Audio('music/fade.mp3');
var spectre = new Audio('music/fade.mp3');
```

So, I want to select that variable when I click and element like this:

```
<div class="item" id="fade">Alan Walker - Fade</div>
<div class="item" id="spectre">Alan Walker - Spectre</div>
```

Here is how I got id:

```
var cs = fade; //default
$('.item').click(function(){
    cs = $(this).get(0).id;
    cs.play();
})
```

but... it wont play audio, console log: `cs.play is not a function`

I want to play music with selected id (with variable).

Comment: Simply use `this.id` not `$(this).get(0).id`.

Comment: Please note that in English, the word I, when referring to yourself, is always capitalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cs` is just a string, so it has no play method. What you need to do is as follows:

```js
var audios = {
  fade: new Audio('music/fade.mp3'),
  spectre = new Audio('music/fade.mp3')
};
var cs = fade; //default
$('.item').click(function(){
  cs = $(this).get(0).id;
  audios[cs].play();
})
```